# How to use mailerlite popups in a Next.js application

Tags: javascript, next.js, jsx

I'm integrating a mailerlite popup for a client's next.js project, and I'm having a difficult time converting the JavaScript snippets into the jsx required to make the popups function properly. On first load it seems to work just fine, but on relaod I'm getting the following error.

```
window is not defined
```

I've encountered the issue while dealing with DOM manipulation, but in this case, judging from the code in the snippet, I need the window object.

*Install the following snippet of Javascript on every page of your website right before the closing  tag.You only need to add this snippet once, even if you plan to have a few different webforms.*

```
<!-- MailerLite Universal -->
<script>
(function(m,a,i,l,e,r){ m['MailerLiteObject']=e;function f(){
var c={ a:arguments,q:[]};var r=this.push(c);return "number"!=typeof r?r:f.bind(c.q);}
f.q=f.q||[];m[e]=m[e]||f.bind(f.q);m[e].q=m[e].q||f.q;r=a.createElement(i);
var _=a.getElementsByTagName(i)[0];r.async=1;r.src=l+'?v'+(~~(new Date().getTime()/1000000));
_.parentNode.insertBefore(r,_);})(window, document, 'script', 'https://static.mailerlite.com/js/universal.js', 'ml');

var ml_account = ml('accounts', '912433', 'd5p1f7l9g0', 'load');
</script>
<!-- End MailerLite Universal -->
```

I've placed this code in my Layout wrapper. As previously stated, it works fine on first load, but as soon as the user navigates to a new page above error shows up.

**PS** I found an old question regarding this topic [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50064898/how-can-i-integrate-a-mailerlite-com-signup-form-with-react/50064899#50064899), but it's old and not quite relevant to my situation. I need to figure out how to convert the above snippet for nextjs. Any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This approach treats the MailerLite universal tag as its own `<script>` hosted on your site's domain.

1. Add a NextJS [custom document](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/custom-document).
2. Create a JavaScript file containing the MailerLite universal tag code in `./public`. I put mine in `./public/scripts/ml.js`.
3. Add a `<script>` tag loading #2 in your custom `_document.js` file:

```
import Document, { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'

class MyDocument extends Document {
  static async getInitialProps(ctx) {
    const initialProps = await Document.getInitialProps(ctx)
    return { ...initialProps }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Html>
        <Head>
          <script async src="/scripts/ml.js"></script>
        </Head>
        <body>
          <Main />
          <NextScript />
        </body>
      </Html>
    )
  }
}

export default MyDocument
```

Everything worked as intended from there! (Caveat: I'm only using embedded forms).